# How to create two different vhosts for two different servers running on same machine

Tags: eclipse, jetty, apache, vhosts

I am running two servers on my machine

> 1. Apache 2.2
>      Running on port 80
>      Accessible at 127.0.0.1
> 2. Jetty
>      Running by Eclipse IDE on port 88
>      Accessible at 127.0.0.1:8888

I can access my apps running on Apache like

`http://127.0.0.1/myapp`

I can create a vhost for above app by

**1.** Adding below line in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

`127.0.0.1  www.myapp.com`

**2.** By adding below code in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@test.com
    DocumentRoot /wwwroot/myapp/
    ServerName myapp.com
    ServerAlias www.myapp.com
    ErrorLog "logs/myapp.com-error.log"
    CustomLog logs/myapp.com-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I can create as many hosts as I want for Apache server but I can't create a vhost for the other server running on port 88 like this

`127.0.0.1:8888     www.myjavaapp.com`

Any suggestion please?